# How can I make Bash automatically pipe the output of every command to something like tee?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I use some magic in `$PROMPT_COMMAND` to automatically save every command I run to a database:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='save_command "$(history 1)"'
```

where `save_command` is a more complicated function.  It would be nice to save also the `head`/`tail` of the output of each command, but I can't think of a reasonable way to do this, other than manually prepending some sort of shell function to everything I type (and this becomes even more painful with complicated pipelines or boolean expressions).  Basically, I just want the first and last 10 lines of whatever went to `/dev/tty` to get saved to a variable (or even a file) - is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

script(1) will probably get you started. It won't let you just record the first and last 10 lines, but you can do some post-processing on its output.

Answer (score 2):

```
bash | tee /dev/tty ./bashout
```

This saves all stdout gets saved to bashout.

```
bash | tee /dev/tty | tail > ./bashout
```

The tail of stdout of every command gets written to bashout.

```
bash | tee /dev/tty | sed -e :a -e '10p;$q;N;11,$D;ba' > ./bashout
```

The first and last 10 lines of stdout of every command gets written to bashout.

These don't save the command, but if you modify your save_command to print the command to stdout, it will get in there.

Comment: Thanks - that's well beyond my current `sed`-fu.  Sadly, this seems to not play well with interactive mode - i.e. it makes bash think that my interactive shell is noninteractive so, for instance, `less` turns into `cat`.  Not sure if there's a quick fix for that, but I've tried to spoof interactive mode in the past and never had success...